# What is wrong with my Dropdown and Label components (working partially)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown, react-select

What is wrong in my Dropdown and Tag components?
Right after selecting my choice from my dropdown, the label gets empty, but in my console log I can see that the right choice is filled.

```
import Select from "react-select";
import Tag from "./Tag";

export default function Dropdown({
  className,
  style,
  options,
  styleSelect,
  value,
  setValue,
  isMulti = false
}) {
  const styles = {
    select: {
      width: "100%",
      maxWidth: 200
    }
  };

  function changeSelect(option) {
    setValue(option.value);
  }

  return (
    <div style={style} onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      {value && isMulti === false ? (
        <Tag
          selected={value}
          setSelected={setValue}
          styleSelect={styleSelect}
        />
      ) : (
        <Select
          className={className}
          style={styles.select}
          value={value}
          onChange={changeSelect}
          options={options}
          isMulti={isMulti}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Tag({ selected, setSelected, styleSelect }) {
  const backgroundColor = styleSelect?.(selected?.label) ?? "blue";
  return (
    <div style={{..}} >
      {selected.label}
      <button style={{...}} onClick={() => setSelected(null)}>
        x
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-fields-with-axios-data-forked-6rdjb1?file=/src/App.js)

Here what I have /what I want:[image]

Comment: Where is `setValue` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Debugging I found out you are accessing incorrect props

In Tag component on line 17 where you are rendering

`{selected.label}`

replace this with

`{selected}`